# Ensuring completion of async OnNext code before process terminates

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The unit test below will never print "Async 3" because the test finishes first. How can I ensure it runs to completion? The best I could come up with was an arbitrary Task.Delay at the end or WriteAsync().Result, neither are ideal.

```
    public async Task TestMethod1() // eg. webjob
    {
        TestContext.WriteLine("Starting test...");
        var observable = Observable.Create<int>(async ob =>
        {
            ob.OnNext(1);
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Fake async REST api call
            ob.OnNext(2);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            ob.OnNext(3);
            ob.OnCompleted();
        });

        observable.Subscribe(i => TestContext.WriteLine($"Sync {i}"));
        observable.SelectMany(i => WriteAsync(i).ToObservable()).Subscribe();

        await observable;
        TestContext.WriteLine("Complete.");
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(int value) // Fake async DB call
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        TestContext.WriteLine($"Async {value}");
    }
```

**Edit**
I realise that mentioning unit tests was probably misleading.This isn't a testing question. The code is a simulation of a real issue of a process running in an Azure WebJob, where both the producer and consumer need to call some Async IO. The issue is that the webjob runs to completion before the consumer has really finished. This is because I can't figure out how to properly await anything from the consumer side. Maybe this just isn't possible with RX...

Comment: You do know that you're creating three separate subscriptions to the underlying observable? Is that your intent here? Or are you trying to share the values of a single observable among three observers?

Comment: 3 subscriptions? Does the 'await observable' cause a subscription too? In the real code the original observable is hot, so I probably should have made it hot in the example too...

Comment: Yes, the `await observable` does cause a third subscription. Your second subscription, `observable.SelectMany(i => WriteAsync(i).ToObservable()).Subscribe()`, has a delay so the `await observable` finishes before it. That's why you're missing the `"Async 3"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
You're basically looking for a blocking operator. The old blocking operators (like `ForEach`) were deprecated in favor of async versions. You want to await the last item like so:

```
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    TestContext.WriteLine("Starting test...");
    var observable = Observable.Create<int>(async ob =>
    {
        ob.OnNext(1);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        ob.OnNext(2);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        ob.OnNext(3);
        ob.OnCompleted();
    });

    observable.Subscribe(i => TestContext.WriteLine($"Sync {i}"));
    var selectManyObservable = observable.SelectMany(i => WriteAsync(i).ToObservable()).Publish().RefCount();
    selectManyObservable.Subscribe();
    await selectManyObservable.LastOrDefaultAsync();
    TestContext.WriteLine("Complete.");
}
```

While that will solve your immediate problem, it looks like you're going to keep running into issues because of the below (and I added two more). Rx is very powerful when used right, and confusing as hell when not.

Old answer:

---

A couple things:

1. Mixing async/await and Rx generally results in getting the pitfalls of both and the benefits of neither.
2. Rx has robust testing functionality. You're not using it.
3. Side-Effects, like a `WriteLine` are best performed exclusively in a subscribe, and not in an operator like `SelectMany`.
4. You may want to brush up on cold vs hot observables.
5. The reason it isn't running to completion is because of your test runner. Your test runner is terminating the test at the conclusion of `TestMethod1`. The Rx subscription would live on otherwise. When I run your code in Linqpad, I get the following output:

   Starting test...
   Sync 1
   Sync 2
   Async 1
   Sync 3
   Async 2
   Complete.
   Async 3

...which is what I'm assuming you want to see, except you probably want the Complete after the Async 3.

---

Using Rx only, your code would look something like this:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    TestContext.WriteLine("Starting test...");
    var observable = Observable.Concat<int>(
        Observable.Return(1),
        Observable.Empty<int>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
        Observable.Return(2),
        Observable.Empty<int>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
        Observable.Return(3)
    );

    var syncOutput = observable
        .Select(i => $"Sync {i}");
    syncOutput.Subscribe(s => TestContext.WriteLine(s));

    var asyncOutput = observable
        .SelectMany(i => WriteAsync(i, scheduler));
    asyncOutput.Subscribe(s => TestContext.WriteLine(s), () => TestContext.WriteLine("Complete."));
}

public IObservable<string> WriteAsync(int value, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Return(value)
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler)
        .Select(i => $"Async {value}");
}


public static class TestContext
{
    public static void WriteLine(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

This still isn't taking advantage of Rx's testing functionality. That would look like this:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    TestContext.WriteLine("Starting test...");
    var observable = Observable.Concat<int>(
        Observable.Return(1),
        Observable.Empty<int>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler),
        Observable.Return(2),
        Observable.Empty<int>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler),
        Observable.Return(3)
    );

    var syncOutput = observable
        .Select(i => $"Sync {i}");
    syncOutput.Subscribe(s => TestContext.WriteLine(s));

    var asyncOutput = observable
        .SelectMany(i => WriteAsync(i, scheduler));
    asyncOutput.Subscribe(s => TestContext.WriteLine(s), () => TestContext.WriteLine("Complete."));

    var asyncExpected = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<string>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms(), "Async 1"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms(), "Async 2"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3000.Ms(), "Async 3"),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<string>(3000.Ms() + 1) //+1 because you can't have two notifications on same tick
    );

    var syncExpected = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<string>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0000.Ms(), "Sync 1"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms(), "Sync 2"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms(), "Sync 3"),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<string>(2000.Ms()) //why no +1 here?
    );

    var asyncObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();
    asyncOutput.Subscribe(asyncObserver);
    var syncObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();
    syncOutput.Subscribe(syncObserver);
    scheduler.Start();
    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(
        asyncExpected.Messages,
        asyncObserver.Messages);

    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(
        syncExpected.Messages,
        syncObserver.Messages);
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static long Ms(this int ms)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms).Ticks;
    }

}
```

...So unlike your Task tests, you don't have to wait. The test executes instantly. You can bump up the Delay times to minutes or hours, and the `TestScheduler` will essentially mock the time for you. And then your test runner will probably be happy.

Comment: If anybody could fill me in on the +1 tick, I would be much obliged.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the question, which was maybe a bit ambiguous -  it wasn't really a question about RX testing although this is something that I intend to learn more about

Comment: Thanks. Edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use [`Observable.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211815%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to block until an `IObservable` has terminated:

```
observable.ForEach(unusedValue => { });
```

Can you make `TestMethod1` a normal, non-async method, and then replace `await observable;` with this?

Comment: No it produces the same output unfortunately (ForEach is deprecated too).

Comment: The OP is already blocking on the `await observable`, but the second subscription runs independently and because it is delayed it finishes later.